# How can I disable bluetooth by default?

Tags: release-hera, bluetooth

I have tried to deactivate the bluetooth as I did in other versions of elementary, but in elementary os hera I did not succeed, which was to edit the file **/etc/rc.local** and add **rfkill block bluetooth**, but in hera the file does not exist.
Could someone tell me how to disable bluetooth in hera?

Answer (score 1):

I recall that the rc.local way of working became obsolete a couple of years ago with the switch of ubuntu to upstart and then to systemd

I'd avoid to uninstall the bluetooth as the bluetoot packages can make you uninstall other important packages (you know, dependencies)

To disable the bluetooth you can try with rfkill or by installing tlp and configuring it properly; you can install tlp by simply typing

```
sudo apt-get install tlp tlp-rdw
```

the user guide on the website is [very detailed and exhaustive](https://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-configuration.html)

But if you don't want to use tlp (which, btw, if you have a notebook, is highly recommended as it makes you save a lot of battery), I think the rfkill solution should work for your case

Answer (score 0):

Remove the bluetooth package:

```
apt remove bluetooth
```